# Invalid operator type of std::istream?

Tags: c++, user-input, istream

So I'm trying to create a C++ program that reads in a list of numbers(where the user enters a list of 5 numbers separated by spaces) and prints out the reversed list. so far, this is what I have:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#pragma warning(disable: 4996)

using namespace std;

int* get_Number() { 
int* p = new int[32];
cout << "Please enter a list of 5 numbers, separated by spaces" << endl;
cin >> p;
return p;
};


int* reverseArray(int* numArray)
{

}
```

My problem is that I keep on getting this error:

```
Error: no operator ">>" matches these operands. Operand types are: std::istream >> int *
```

at the `cin >> p` line.

What am I doing wrong? I'm new to C++, and any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int nums[5];

    std::cout << "Please enter a list of 5 numbers, separated by spaces" << std::endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
        std::cin >> nums[i];

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
        std::cout << nums[i];
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean `cin >> p[i]`, where `i` is an index missing in your code?

Currently you're reading to a pointer, but you intended to read into your array, right?

Try this

```
int* get_Number() { 
    int* p = new int[32];
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
       cout << "Please enter a number" << endl;
       cin >> p[i];
    }
    return p;
};
```

Comment: Right, I wanted to read in an array.. I thought I could read in a pointer to an array.

Comment: Well, the compiler is telling you that you can't.

Comment: Thanks, I understood my mistake with that, and I should have been more clear in my question, but the problem is that I need to read in all 5 numbers at once.

Comment: Try: `scanf ("%d %d %d %d %d",&p[0], &p[1], &p[2], &p[3], &p[4]);` It's not the most graceful way, but should do the trick.

Comment: @banach-space what is stopping from using loop instead?

Comment: @Logan Too many years coding in C and being forbidden to use C++ ;-)

Comment: @banach-space umm, C has loops too! `for(int i=0; i<5;++i) scanf("%d", &p[i]);`

Answer (score 1):

You're better off using [`getline`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/)

```
string line;
cin.getline(line);
```

It will do nice stuff for you like resizing it.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the getline, I think it will be useful in the future! However, I want to create an array of integers so I'm not sure that I want to use getline in this case

Comment: To enforce an input such as 5 numbers separated by spaces, you *have* to use something like ``getline``.

Comment: Oh... I see. that makes more sense.